# Developing Android apps without Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse

Everyone uses Eclipse for developing apps for android apps. I hate using IDEs. Is there any tutorial available for android app development without IDEs?

Comment: Stop hating IDEs.

Comment: true - hate never helps getting you forward

Comment: In fact, the recommended IDE is [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) ;)

Comment: Yes but you will regret it. Ide's exist to make coding simpler. Just learn one because any real production environment will be using one.

Comment: you don't need an IDE but here is a similar question to yours: <http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/125111/do-i-need-an-ide-to-develop-android-apps>

Comment: Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA, not Eclipse.

Comment: I don't hate IDEs. That's not what I meant. I just feel the power when I program in notepad.

Comment: You're trolling. `I just feel the power when I program in notepad`

Comment: No, I just mean that I feel good when I so it all myself because IDE does half of the work.

Comment: `Everyone uses Eclipse for developing apps for android` **NOT TRUE**.

Comment: `because IDE does half of the work` if you believe that, then perhaps software is not for you.  The IDE will do precisely nothing to help you to write good code, to provide software that people want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do Android development completely without IDE using building systems such as Ant or Gradle. For Ant check [Ant](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html). For Gradle check [Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide). However like others are recommending - do not hate IDEs because they speed up your development process.